# C# generic ClientBase with interface confusion

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

The C# definition of [ClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

```
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, 
    IDisposable
where TChannel : class
```

Which clearly indicates the `class` constraint on the `TChannel` type.  To the best of my knowledge, that means that you *cannot* use and interface type for the generic when declaring your own class.  So given a service declared thusly:

```
public IMyService
...
public MyService : IMyService
...
```

This should work:

```
public MyServiceClient : ClientBase<MyService>
```

This should *NOT*:

```
public MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyService>
```

But clearly I am not understanding because the example shows a declaration of:

```
public partial class SampleServiceClient : 
    System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ISampleService>, ISampleService
```

And more to the point, I am trying to abstract the authentication, and proper closing of the client with a utility method:

```
    public TResult WithClient<TInterface, T, TResult>(T service, 
        Func<TInterface, TResult> callback)
        where T : ClientBase<TInterface>, TInterface
    {
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        try
        {
            var result = callback(service);
            service.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception unknown)
        {
            service.Abort();
            throw unknown;
        }
    }
```

But this gives me the compiler error:

```
The type 'TInterface' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TChannel' in the generic type or method 'ClientBase<TChannel>'
```

Can somebody clear the confusion here?  What am I doing wrong?

**---- UPDATE ----**

Per @InBetween, the resolution is to add the `where TInterface : class` constraint to my utility method:

```
    public TResult WithClient<TInterface, T, TResult>(T service, 
        Func<TInterface, TResult> callback)
        where TInterface : class
        where T : ClientBase<TInterface>, TInterface
    {
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        try
        {
            var result = callback(service);
            service.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception unknown)
        {
            service.Abort();
            throw unknown;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `class` constraint constraints the generic type to a reference type. An interface is, by definition, a reference type. What you can't do is use a value type as the generic type: `ClientBase<int>` would be a compile time error.

Comment: @InBetween, dammit, thats the key i was not understanding...  if you wanna make that comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `class` constraint constraints the generic type to a reference type. An interface is, by definition, a reference type. What you can't do is use a value type as the generic type: `ClientBase<int>` would be a compile time error.

As to the second error, you are not constraining `TInterface` and then using it in`ClientBase<TInterface>`. Because `ClientBase` constraints its generic type to reference types (`class`), you need to constraint `TInterface` accordingly.