# A simpler generic ClientBase factory

Tags: c#, .net, generics, factory, webservice-client

After reading [C# generic ClientBase with interface confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949583/c-sharp-generic-clientbase-with-interface-confusion) I managed to create a Soap Webservice Factory that simplifies my code:

```
private T ClientMaker<TInterface, T>(string username, string password, string address)
    where TInterface : class 
    where T : ClientBase<TInterface>, TInterface
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

    EndpointAddress ordersEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(address);

    T client = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { binding, ordersEndpoint }) as T;

    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

    return client;
}
```

and is used like this:

```
var client = ClientMaker<CreateWebOrder.WEB_Functions_Port, CreateWebOrder.WEB_Functions_PortClient>(user, pass, endpointBase + "Codeunit/WEB_Functions");
```

`CreateWebOrder.WEB_Functions_Port is the interface implemented by CreateWebOrder.WEB_Functions_PortClient`

One thing I don't like so much is that I need to supply the interface AND the class/type of the webservice, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this by fishing out the interface or class from the type-parameter.

Considering that the return type is ClientBase and TInterface is known because of the supplied type-parameter, why do i then need to supply the "PortClient" ?

Ideally I'd like to call the factory with only 1 type parameter, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: For me there are too many things happening that "ClientMaker" - This is also not a real factory just more of a helper. I suspect most of the complexity is coming from the inheritance with the generic on it.. the signature, as you rightly say is just to complex.

Comment: Why are you creating this class in the first place instead of using the proxy created by `Add Service Reference` ? All those settings are typically set through configuration. The `Add Service Reference` dialog will even add the appropriate configuration settings to your app.config or web.config

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos doing it this way i can inject a configuration or environment parameter into the code and change all parameters on the fly. Also, we don't have an infrastructure where config files are used like they should :-(

Comment: That's already provided out-of-the-box - that's why bindings are separate classes. They are meant to be injected into the proxy. On the other hand, your class *hard-codes* both the bindings and the configuration. What happens when you inevitably have to switch to HTTPS? You'll have to recompile the code instead of just changing some configuration setting to modify the security mode

Comment: You don't have to use the generated web.config or app.config. You can use the proxy and provide your own bindings and address to it (in fact, everyone provides a custom address in production). Those classes can be generated from any kind of configuration.

Comment: To communicate intent we name methods in a certain way. "Make" should be avoided. "CreateClient" should be used for the factory method pattern. "BuildClient" if you are using the builder pattern.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

That functionality is already provided out of the box. Given an annotated interface :

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface IMath
{
    [OperationContract()]
     double Add(double A, double B);
}
```

You can create a factory for a specific binding and endpoint :

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

//configure the binding ........ then 

EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MathService/Ep1");

ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

// Create a channel.
IMath wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
double s = wcfClient1.Add(3, 39);
```

**Long explanation**

WCF already provides factories for all those things, in fact, it has too many of them and not enough docs - back in 2008 people though that everyone would generate a client proxy from WS-* standard compliant WSDL, and configured through XML.

Back then everyone really thought that XML was the solution to everything, just like everyone thought JSON would be the solution 5 years ago, or YAML 2 years ago.

A client uses behaviors. Behaviors combine endpoints and bindings. All of those can be created in code and injected as needed. WCF provides infrastructure to load the settings from app.config/web.config files. Unfortunately, this configuration infrastructure can't be easily customized and the the `How To` documents don't show the entire process of constructing a channel programmatically, because it was considered an `advanced` case.

Factories for the bindings, the endpoints, the message envelopes, the bodies, etc. Nobody thought to document all of them because they though everyone would use tools to generate the proxies.

For example the [WCF Client Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview) shows how to create the interface and client base, but 4 of the 5 constructors either use default configuration or expect configuration names. The last one though, accepts both a Binding and an EndpointAddress. No need for hard-coding eg :

```
public partial class SampleServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ISampleService>, ISampleService
{
    public SampleServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        :base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
}
```

Generating that code each time is impractical, especially when the behaviors need to change. Eg, to add encryption, or inspect/modify custom headers. So WCF offers a ChannelFactory for "advanced" scenarios. That's also used by the proxy too, to cache Behavior, binding and endpoint instances. The docs are in the "advanced" section though [How to: Use the ChannelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory).

From that doc example, it's as simple as :

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface IMath
{
    [OperationContract()]
     double Add(double A, double B);
}


private void Run()
{
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MathService/Ep1");

        ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

        // Create a channel.
        IMath wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        double s = wcfClient1.Add(3, 39);
}
```

**Why did I write the examples in reverse order?**

Precisely because the ChannelFactory is "hidden" in the advanced features. I found the programmatic client example first, then [Configuring Client Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-client-behaviors) which pointed to ClientFactory and finally, [How To: Use the ChannelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clean up your signature. Reduce the amount of parameters. Using the book Clean Code as reference, one parameter is already one parameters too much. This makes sense if you can implement Inversion Of Control but really in this case it just means create a POCO/DTO/Class to pass your data around. This satisfies the Open/Closed principle

```
public class EndpointDetails{
    public string UserName {get; set;}  
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

and then

```
private T ClientMaker<TInterface, T>(EndpointDetails endpointDetails)
```

"ClienMaker" does not really mean any thing to me and is misleading. In C# we should be fluent with meaning of code so name things meaningfully (also from Clean Code) - After looking at the code I would name it **MakeClientWithSettings()** - because that is what is what it will be doing in the code below that I suggest.

Also this is NOT a factory... don't confuse things by calling it that. If it was a factory you would just call `Create()` with NO PARAMETERS! and it would now how to create everything by leveraging DI ([reference to what a factory could be](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm))

Now to clean up all the generics, as you rightly pointed out is a bit much it all depends on the dependencies that are required.

**In my opinion there is just way tooooo much happening there in that one method**

- This means there is more than one concern in the class (violates Single Responsibility)
- Somebody really clutching at straws to make things "generic"

So I can try and help you refactor this but I do not know the context around the code so this is what I came up with - This might probably not compile so you need to adjust I am just doing this manually in notepad.

Essentially the jist here is

- that the Generic you are passing in can also be passed out.
- The only thing that resembles a factory here is that we are manually new'ing up
- The return type with generic is type checked by inference

  ```
  private ClientBase<TInterface> MakeClientWithSettings<TInterface>(EndpointDetails endpointDetails)
      where TInterface : class 
  {
      var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
      binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
      binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
      binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
      binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
      EndpointAddress ordersEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointDetails.Address);

      //T client = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[]{binding, ordersEndpoint}) as T;
      var client = new ClientBase<T>(binding, ordersEndpoint);

      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = endpointDetails.Username;
      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = endpointDetails.Password;

          return client;
  }
  ```

---

So as per comments from `Panagiotis Kanavos` it really seems this should actually be done differently and the source of the pain is by trying to force it the other way around.

It sounds like you need to leverage your Dependency Injection container to handle the dependencies in the scope required, PerRequest or PerSession (Transient) and that there is ALREADY a factory in WCF that can do all the binding for you.

This is pseudo code (I dont know any of this client stuff you working with the ? is probably another class you need to use or and Interface)

```
services.AddTransient<BasicHttpBinding>(() => new BasicHttpBinding(*))
services.AddTransient<EndpointAddress>(() = EndpointAddress(*))
services.AddTransient<Client?>(ClientFactory) <-- the dependencies here are the ones you need to inject above
```

And then you just use the Client where ever you need by injection it in the constructor of the class

```
public OrderSystem(Client? client){

   client.DoReqeust()

}
```

Comment: This isn't much of an improvement, as both the Binding and EndpointAddress classes are meant to be *injected* in WCF. They are created and configured individually. In the default case, the configuration comes from XML configuration

Comment: Panagiotis - I have not worked with this in many many years. Yes I agree this code is far from ideal but it is one step cleaner than that of the original question. Also, I do not really know the context of why the OP wants to ... or needs to do this. My next step would be create a real factory, using the injection technique you mention but also injection the EndpointDetails to marry everything up

Comment: In fact, endpoint and binding are separate concerns. Multiple endpoints can use the same binding for example, while the binding used with *one* endpoint can change, eg from HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: So what you are saying really though.. Is to inject EndpointAddress, Binding and ClientBase<T>, which can then be injected into consumers?

Comment: that's the point - WCF already provides those factories, in fact, it has too many of them and not enough docs. Factories for the bindings, the endpoints, the message envelopes, the bodies, etc. Nobody thought to document all of them because they though everyone would use tools to generate the proxies

Comment: This is probably where all the confusion is coming from because the link to the other answers seems like the guy really struggled to create this beast which is always a red flag for me. As in that is probably the wrong way. I just wanted to help the OP answer his original question.. but by the sounds of it.. they should not be doing it this way in the first place